# The provided route key is not formatted properly for HTTP protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-http-api

> An error occurred: **HttpApiRoutePostv1Banks** - The provided route key is
> not formatted properly for HTTP protocol. Format should be "[HTTP
> METHOD] /[RESOURCE PATH]" or "$default" (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2;
> Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID:
> 38370b30-9c11-4a66-9f2d-710fd2c25329; Proxy: null).

```
provider:
  ...
  httpApi:
    payload: '2.0' # Define Http format needed for API GW
  ...
functions:
  banksCreate:
    handler: src/banks.create
    events:
      - httpApi: 'POST v1/banks'
```

I had set up serverless.yml file according to the [official documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api/)

when I run serverless offline everything working fine, but when I try to deploy error above occurs.

I am not sure where I make a mistake?

note that deployment was ok with **restApi** event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE**: error message says `[HTTP METHOD] /[RESOURCE PATH]`
which means that `/` should at path start and path be separated by blank space.

```
provider:
  ...
  httpApi:
    payload: '2.0' # Define Http format needed for API GW
  ...
functions:
  banksCreate:
    handler: src/banks.create
    events:
      - httpApi: 'POST /v1/banks'
```